# How can I iterate over all days in a given range that are in a specific day of week?

Tags: php

I have the following function in php:

```
function iterateDays(Carbon $from, Carbon $to, int dayOfWeek,Closure $method){

   for($start=$from;$from->lessThanOrEqualTo($to);$from=$from->modify("+1 day"){
      if($from->dayOfWeek == $dayOfWeek){
          $method($from);
      } 
   }
}
```

But as you can see I need to iterate all days in order to check each day that matches the day of week that exists in range $from - $to causing me to have extra steps in the loop.

So how I can Increment the $from with the right number of days that matches the next day that has the appropriate day of week?

The $day of week is an integer between [0-6] where 0 = Sunday and 6 = Saturday.

Comment: Your function has simple syntax errors, so not sure how you are using it.

Comment: 1) Check if `$from` matches the desired day. If not, find the next date that does. 2) Do the same for `$to`, but find the previous, not next. 3) Use those dates to create a period with a 7 day interval.